# Multipart upload initiated with putObject is aborted (AWS Javascript SDK)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, multipart

I'm using the AWS JS Javascript SDK in the browser and trying to upload user selected large files to the user's designated folder on S3.

I use the putObject method to upload files to S3. The user is authenticated with a temporary token generated server side, and is allowed to putObject in a specific folder on the bucket.

When the file is under 5MB, it works fine. When the file is over 5MB, the AbortMultiupload method is called after the first chunk fails.

What causes this?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was "No access to ETag property on response. Check CORS configuration". Solved it with adding "ETag" in bucket CORS configuration.